# Скролинг фиксированного блока при маленьком разрешении

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть фиксированный блок, у него высота 1100 пикселей, но если кто-то заходит, и экран меньше 1100 пикселей  - то нет прокрутки до конца блока... Как решить проблему?

```css
.fixed-bg{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 1100px;
 width: 500px;
 color: white;
 border: 2px solid lime;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bg">

</div>
```

Comment: поменять `position: fixed;` на `position: absolute;`

Comment: В том то и дело, что оно фиксированое быть должно..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var fY = 0;
    $("#scrollFixedBlock").ready(function(){
        $("#scrollFixedBlock").bind('mousewheel', function(e){
            if(e.originalEvent.deltaY>0){
                if(fY>=( -parseInt( $("#scrollFixedBlock").css('height') ) )+window.innerHeight ){
                    fY -=100;
                    $("#scrollFixedBlock").stop().animate({"top":fY}, '500', 'linear', function() {});
                }
            }else{
                if(fY<=0){
                    fY +=100;
                    $("#scrollFixedBlock").stop().animate({"top":fY}, '500', 'linear', function() {});

                }
            }
           return false; 
        });
    });
```

Просто при прокрутке меняете css свойство **top**